# A problem involving induction and upper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, induction

Use induction to prove that, if A1, ..., An are upper triangular matrices of the same size, then $\sum_{i=1}^n A_i$ is upper triangular.

How do i do this problem?

Thank You

Comment: Do you have to use induction?  It's already pretty clear.

Comment: yeah I have to. I understand the induction but I do not understand on how should I use it with matrices.

Comment: Use induction over $n$. The key to the induction step is showing that, if $A$ and $B$ are upper-triangular, then $A + B$ is upper-triangular. Then, the induction step becomes $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} A_i = \sum_{i=1}^n A_i + A_{n+1}$, where $\sum_{i=1}^n A_i$ is upper-triangular by the inductive hypothesis.

Comment: Alright I will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is upper triangular **iff** $e_i^T Ae_j = 0$ for all $i>j$.

Suppose $A,B$ are upper triangular, then $e_i^T (A+B)e_j = 0$ for all $i>j$ and so
$A+B$ is upper triangular.

Hence if $A_1+\cdots +A_n$ and $A_{n+1}$ are upper triangular, then so is $A_1+\cdots +A_{n+1}$.

Comment: Appreciate the extra help